# getting error when generating password hash in flask

Tags: flask

I am building a `web-application` in flask and one of the modules I am adding to it is the user module which contains the information from the users including ID, email, password and role.
For the password I am trying to generate a password hash but in my flask shell I cannot add the password to the database (however I can add email AND also if I do not generate password hash, I can add password too).
For the user module I made a Blueprint and a separate folder which includes `models.py` and `__init__.py`.

Here is the `app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from config import Development

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Development)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Home page"


from mod_users import users
app.register_blueprint(users)
```

And for the users module (folder), here is the `__init__.py` file:

```
from flask import Blueprint

users = Blueprint('users', __name__, url_prefix='/users/')
from .models import User


@users.route('/')
def user_index():
    return "Hello from User index"
```

And here is the `models.py` :

```
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from app import db


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    ID = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(128), nullable=False , unique=True)
    password = Column(String(128), nullable=False, unique=False)
    role = Column(Integer(), nullable=False, default=0)


def set_password(self, password):
    self.password = generate_password_hash(password)
```

In my flask shell :

```
from mod_users.models import User
from app import db
user = User()
user.email = ‘myemail@hgku.er’
user.set_password('123456')
```

For the last line I will get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'set_password'
```

But if I do:

```
user.password = ‘123456’
```

It works and I can add it to the database.
Do you know how I can fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

your indentation in the User object is apparently wrong. if you want set_password to be a class function, you have to indent it into the User class scope

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    ID = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(128), nullable=False , unique=True)
    password = Column(String(128), nullable=False, unique=False)
    role = Column(Integer(), nullable=False, default=0)


    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password = generate_password_hash(password)
```